# Make a Toast in Request Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I want to make a toast but the Toast doesn't get printed

```
  Request r = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();

                client.newCall(r).enqueue(new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "password wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Every UI update in android has to be executed in UI thread:**

Run the following code in onFailure

```
Login.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() { Toast.makeText(Login.this, "password wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
});
```